# 'Contact.Contact' has no ForeignKey to 'Order.Order' error using django extra views

Tags: django

I'm trying to use django extra views to create an Order with a Contact inline formset but i'm getting the following error : **'Contact.Contact' has no ForeignKey to 'Order.Order'**.

**models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
...

class Order(models.Model):
    contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

**views.py**

```
class ContactInline(InlineFormSetFactory):
    model = Contact
    fields = ['name', 'email']


class CreateOrderView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Order
    inlines = [ContactInline]
    fields = ['customer', 'name']
    template_name = 'order_and_items.html'
```

I am wordering if the problem is due to the OneToOne relationship between Contact and Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateWithInlinesView` works perfectly well with the `OneToOneField` relation, as this is just a foreign key under the hood, but with an unique constraint. But you need to use it the other way around.

As the view expects the foreign key to be defined in the view you want to inline, you need to either specify the `Order` in your inline formset and use the `Contact` model in your view (which probably doesn't make sense, as the `Order` is the main model in your example) or move the `OneToOneField` to the `Contact` model, as below:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", related_name="contact")

class Order(models.Model):
    ...
```